# How to display form validation error messages accurately for more than two input fields using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, if-statement

I have created a JavaScript function that checks a form during submitting the input and displays an error message if there's no input.

It works perfectly when none input is given. It displays all the error messages correctly.

**The Problem:** But if I leave just the first field blank i.e, the `fullname`; the if loop stops there and doesn't display the second or third error messages i.e, the `streetaddr` & `quantity`.

**NOTE: This error happens only when one of `streetaddr` or `quantity` is not given with addition to the first field i.e, `fullname`.**

What should I do to display the error messages  correctly. According to the blank input regardless the input field comes first or second or third.

**Also, I prefer to do this with just Vanilla JavaScript, no frameworks/libraries. I'm trying to learn!**

Link(s): [This is a challenge from Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Web_Design/JavaScript_Challenges)

```js
/* Checking form function */
function checkForm(){
 window.alert("You clicked Submit!");
 var fullNameCheck = document.getElementById("fullname");
 var addressCheck = document.getElementById("streetaddr");
 var quantityCheck = document.getElementById("quantity");
 var is_valid = false;
 /* If statements to check if text box is empty */
 if (fullNameCheck.value=="" && addressCheck.value=="" && quantityCheck.value=="") {
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  is_valid = false;
 } else if(fullNameCheck.value==""){
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display="none";
  is_valid = false;
 } else if (addressCheck.value==""){
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display="none";
  is_valid = false;
 } else if (quantityCheck.value==""){
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display="none";
  is_valid = false;
 } else {
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display="none";
  is_valid = true;

 } return is_valid;
}
```

```css
.errormsg{
 color: red;
 background-color: yellow;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
    <fieldset>

      <legend>Personal details</legend>
      <p>
        <label>
          Full name:
          <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="nameerrormsg">Please enter your name above</p>

      <p>
        <label>
          Street Address:
          <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="addrerrormsg">Please enter your street address</p>

      <!-- Quantity input -->
      <p>
        <label>
          Quantity:
          <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="qtyerrormsg">Please enter your quantity</p>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit it!"> 
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide all the error text as initially. Then show the error text based on respected input failure

```js
/* Checking form function */
function checkForm() {
  window.alert("You clicked Submit!");
  var fullNameCheck = document.getElementById("fullname");
  var addressCheck = document.getElementById("streetaddr");
  var quantityCheck = document.getElementById("quantity");
  var is_valid = false;
  /* If statements to check if text box is empty */
  document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display = "none";
  is_valid = true;

  if (fullNameCheck.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("nameerrormsg").style.display = "inline";
    is_valid = false;
  }
  if (addressCheck.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("addrerrormsg").style.display = "inline";
    is_valid = false;
  }
  if (quantityCheck.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("qtyerrormsg").style.display = "inline";
    is_valid = false;
  }
  return is_valid;
}
```

```css
.errormsg {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>Personal details</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
          Full name:
          <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p class="errormsg" id="nameerrormsg">Please enter your name above</p>

    <p>
      <label>
          Street Address:
          <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p class="errormsg" id="addrerrormsg">Please enter your street address</p>

    <!-- Quantity input -->
    <p>
      <label>
          Quantity:
          <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p class="errormsg" id="qtyerrormsg">Please enter your quantity</p>

  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit it!">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your method was the easiest to understand.
This answer is good for beginners.

Comment: Ok! A question: is there any way to use the statements with `else if`? 
Multiple calls to the if statements, is kinda complicated, no?

Comment: Else if not possible .Because else if only execute  if statement  fails. For your case else if not possible  . And also multiple if is not complicated . if you need a more simplified version use any loops like next answer

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to just make the fields `required`, no Javascript needed:

```html
<form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>Personal details</legend>
    <p>
      <label>
          Full name:
          <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" required>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label>
          Street Address:
          <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr" required>
        </label>
    </p>

    <!-- Quantity input -->
    <p>
      <label>
          Quantity:
          <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" required>
        </label>
    </p>

  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit it!">
</form>
```

Otherwise, you can first hide all the error messages. Iterate over all inputs in the form, and if invalid (missing), navigate to its ancestor `p` and then to the adjacent `.errormsg` and set its display.

It would also be a good idea to [avoid inline handlers entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have too many problems to be worth using. Attach listeners properly using `addEventListener` in Javascript instead.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
  for (const errormsg of document.querySelectorAll('.errormsg')) {
    errormsg.style.display = 'none';
  }
  let valid = true;
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('form input')) {
    if (input.value) {
      // valid
      continue;
    }
    valid = false;
    input.closest('p').nextElementSibling.style.display = 'inline';
  }
  return valid;
});
```

```css
.errormsg{
 color: red;
 background-color: yellow;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com">
    <fieldset>

      <legend>Personal details</legend>
      <p>
        <label>
          Full name:
          <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="nameerrormsg">Please enter your name above</p>

      <p>
        <label>
          Street Address:
          <input type="text" name="streetaddr" id="streetaddr">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="addrerrormsg">Please enter your street address</p>

      <!-- Quantity input -->
      <p>
        <label>
          Quantity:
          <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="errormsg" id="qtyerrormsg">Please enter your quantity</p>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit it!"> 
  </form>
```

Comment: I love the way you solved this! It is a little bit complicated. But another point of view, really helps.
Making use of `for` loop with `if` statements is really interesting. Thanks for your solution.